# Fire triggers on SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select, triggers

I'm new to triggers and I need to fire a trigger when selecting values from a database table in sql server. I have tried firing triggers on insert/update and delete. is there any way to fire trigger when selecting values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two ways I know that you can do this and neither are trigger.

1. You can use a stored procedure to run the query and log the query to a table and other information you'd like to know.
2. You can use the [audit feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) of SQL Server.

I've never used the latter, so I can't speak of the ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no provision of having trigger on SELECT operation. As suggested in earlier answer, write a stored procedure which takes parameters that are fetched from SEECT query and call this procedure after desired SELECT query.

Answer (score -2):

SpectralGhost's answer assumes you are trying to do something like a security audit of who or what has looked at which data.

But it strikes me if you are new enough to sql not to know that a SELECT trigger is conceptually daft, you may be trying to do something else, in which case you're really talking about locking rather than auditing - i.e. once one process has read a particular record you want to prevent other processes accessing it (or possibly some other related records in a different table) until the transaction is either committed or rolled back. In that case, triggers are definitely not your solution (they rarely are). See BOL on transaction control and locking

Comment: Chamara is the asker. You meant someone else, perhaps?

Comment: I beg your pardon - my mistake. That should be SpectralGhost's answer.

Comment: I assumed it was for auditing purposes (not necessarily security) because I couldn't think of any scenario you would want that information otherwise. As far as worrying about transactions being committed, that should not be a concern if properly using locks and read levels.

Comment: Just because you can not think of a reason for a feature does not make someone that has a reason daft. I don't have enough room in a comment to share my use case but I assure you that it is not daft and a select trigger, if such a thing existed, would be a wonderful solution. Hint: sometimes an entity has access to the code for the DDL but not the DML. They have the ability to add/change/delete database triggers but not the application itself. I admit that getting yourself into that situation is daft but lots of businesses do it. People hired into a situation like that need a solution.