# Find out the popularity of values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 1000 rows. Each row represents a prompt text for an application. For the start I only want to translate the most used 20% of the promts. In the daily use some dialogs appear more often than others. So the prompt texts for the most displayed dialogs get fetched more often than the others.
However, it looks to me like there is no built-in mechanism to analyse the data by their select rates.

There are no triggers on select. There is no way to filter the data in the profiler. There is no way to filter data in an Audit. Is that true?

Are there any options to do that inside the SQL Server?

Comment: The description of what you're trying to achieve here is hazy at best. Could you try to elaborate? perhaps include some sample data along with expected results to explain your goals better. As it stands your goals are unclear.

Comment: query with a stored procedure in stead of a direct select statement. In the stored procedure you might be able to assign points to the requested text

Comment: There is an audit under security in SSMS but not sure if that will do what you need.

Comment: Program the application to log the prompts.  It could be done in stored procedures as Guido suggests, or you could write an application function that does it to centralize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire triggers on SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604191/fire-triggers-on-select)

Comment: GuidoG thanks, but that's not an option. The values in the table are read by a third party application. I cannot modify how the application gets the translations, I can only monitor the table the values are read from.

@paparazzo - no, Audit is not an option, it does not allow to monitor values, it only alows to monitor selects on the table

TabAlleman changes in the application are not an option, third party app. Possible duplicate, however, the duplicate was not solved in that there was no solution that would work for me.

Comment: @GuidoG sorry, seems like one cannot notify multiple users in one comment, please read above

Comment: @TabAlleman please read my comment above, thanks

Comment: Well exactly, sometimes the answer is "no, there's nothing you can do", and the duplicate gives that answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no way to track the frequency of how often data is selected.

This sounds like application metrics.  You will have to write metrics logic yourself.

For example, you might create a table of MissingTranslations that tracks the frequency of requests.  If your application detects a missing translation, insert a row into this table with a frequency of 1, or increment the counter if it already exists in the table.

You could then write another application that sorts the missing translations by frequency descending.  When a user enters the translation, the translation app removes the entry from the list of missing translations or marks it as complete.

*All that being said*, you could abuse some SQL Server features to get some information.  For example, a stored procedure that returns these translations could generate a [user-configurable trace event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/user-configurable-event-class) with the translation info.  A SQL Profiler session could listen for these events and write them to a table.  This would get you a basic frequency.

It might be possible to get the same information from implementing auditing and then calling [`sys.fn_get_audit_file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql), but that sounds cumbersome at best.

In my opinion, it sounds easier and more stable to me to write this logic yourself.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was looking for a pure SQL Server solution. I cannot change the way the app queries the translations as it's a closed code third party application. As far as I understand it (by creating a new Audit on the table) the audit can only monitor selects but not the values the select returns. 
I thought maybe there is some SQL Server statistics module that just needs to be turned on, or sth like that, but so it seems like there is no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

@TabAlleman: "no, there's nothing you can do"